# jQuery .next() and .previous()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Aug: <input type="text" value="100000" name="targetMonth_8" id="targetMonth_8" class="targetMonth" disabled>
Sep: <input type="text" value="100000" name="targetMonth_9" id="targetMonth_9" class="targetMonth" disabled>
Oct: <input type="text" value="100000" name="targetMonth_10" id="targetMonth_10" class="targetMonth active">
Nov: <input type="text" value="100000" name="targetMonth_11" id="targetMonth_11" class="targetMonth active">
Dec: <input type="text" value="100000" name="targetMonth_12" id="targetMonth_12" class="targetMonth active">
```

For the purpose of this demo, pretend the current month is October. AUG/SEP is not editable because it is prior to the current month (October). Therefore, Oct, Nov and Dec are editable. If the user edits October, I want to dynamically get the next active input, where I will be making changes so as to auto-balance the system.

I also have an indicator on the page to set whether the NEXT or PREVIOUS month is to be targeted for auto-balancing.

eg:
*if indicator is DOWNWARDS then*

- if user edits Oct, I want to know the id of Nov and its value.
- if user edits Nov, I want to know the id of Dec and its value.
- if user edits Dec, I want to know the id of Oct and its value.

*if indicator is UPWARDS then*

- if user edits Oct, I want to know the id of Dec and its value.
- if user edits Nov, I want to know the id of Oct and its value.
- if user edits Dec, I want to know the id of Nov and its value.

How would I use jQuery to dynamically get the name and value of the NEXT or PREVIOUS input WHERE CLASS is "active"?

ie:

```
<script>
$('#targetMonth_{$monthNumber}').keyup(function() {
  balanceDirection = $('#balanceDirectionValue').val();
  if (balanceDirection=='down') {
    balanceInputID = <next input's ID>;
    balanceInputValue = <next input's value>;
  }
  if (balanceDirection=='up') {
    balanceInputID = <previous input's ID>;
    balanceInputValue = <previous input's value>;
  }
}
</script>
```

I've tried using:

> $('#targetMonth_{$monthNumber}').nextAll('.active').val()

Something like that, I'm not sure... Please assist. I'm open to changes if this can be done in another way.

Answer (score 0):

yup, that should work:

```
the_val = $('#targetMonth_{$monthNumber}').nextAll('.active').val();
the_id = $('#targetMonth_{$monthNumber}').nextAll('.active').attr('id');
```

those variables may be arrays

Comment: I think the problem is because each input has a unique name.. Which i need for the form post to the next page for saving to the db..